# Event not being called on Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, events

***Problematic code***

```
<Canvas x:Name="CanvaContainer" Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="Transparent" Height="360" Width="540" MouseMove="CanvaContainer_MouseMove" MouseLeftButtonDown="CanvaContainer_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseRightButtonDown="CanvaContainer_MouseRightButtonDown">
            <Grid x:Name="GridContainer" Background="Transparent" Height="360" Width="540">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Height="{Binding ElementName=CanvaContainer, Path=ActualHeight}" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter"/>
                <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Height="{Binding ElementName=CanvaContainer, Path=ActualHeight}" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter"/>
                <Rectangle Grid.Column="2" Height="{Binding ElementName=CanvaContainer, Path=ActualHeight}" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter"/>
                <Rectangle Grid.Column="3" Height="{Binding ElementName=CanvaContainer, Path=ActualHeight}" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter"/>
                <Rectangle Grid.Column="4" Height="{Binding ElementName=CanvaContainer, Path=ActualHeight}" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter"/>
                <Rectangle Grid.Column="5" Height="{Binding ElementName=CanvaContainer, Path=ActualHeight}" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter"/>
                <Rectangle Grid.Column="6" Height="{Binding ElementName=CanvaContainer, Path=ActualHeight}" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter"/>
                <Rectangle Grid.Column="7" Height="{Binding ElementName=CanvaContainer, Path=ActualHeight}" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter"/>
                <Rectangle Grid.Column="8" Height="{Binding ElementName=CanvaContainer, Path=ActualHeight}" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter"/>
                <Rectangle Grid.Column="9" Height="{Binding ElementName=CanvaContainer, Path=ActualHeight}" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter"/>
                <Rectangle Grid.Column="10" Height="{Binding ElementName=CanvaContainer, Path=ActualHeight}" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter"/>
                <Rectangle Grid.Column="11" Height="{Binding ElementName=CanvaContainer, Path=ActualHeight}" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter"/>
            </Grid>
        </Canvas>
```

***Whole code***

```
 <Grid Name="GraphGrid" Background="Transparent" Margin="140,30,0,0" Width="582" Height="620" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Border x:Name="CanvasBorder" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="40,230,0,0" >
            <Canvas x:Name="CanvaContainer" Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="Transparent" Height="360" Width="540" MouseMove="CanvaContainer_MouseMove" MouseLeftButtonDown="CanvaContainer_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseRightButtonDown="CanvaContainer_MouseRightButtonDown">
                <Grid x:Name="GridContainer" Background="Transparent" Height="360" Width="540">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Height="{Binding ElementName=CanvaContainer, Path=ActualHeight}" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter"/>
                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Height="{Binding ElementName=CanvaContainer, Path=ActualHeight}" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter"/>
                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="2" Height="{Binding ElementName=CanvaContainer, Path=ActualHeight}" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter"/>
                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="3" Height="{Binding ElementName=CanvaContainer, Path=ActualHeight}" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter"/>
                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="4" Height="{Binding ElementName=CanvaContainer, Path=ActualHeight}" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter"/>
                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="5" Height="{Binding ElementName=CanvaContainer, Path=ActualHeight}" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter"/>
                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="6" Height="{Binding ElementName=CanvaContainer, Path=ActualHeight}" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter"/>
                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="7" Height="{Binding ElementName=CanvaContainer, Path=ActualHeight}" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter"/>
                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="8" Height="{Binding ElementName=CanvaContainer, Path=ActualHeight}" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter"/>
                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="9" Height="{Binding ElementName=CanvaContainer, Path=ActualHeight}" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter"/>
                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="10" Height="{Binding ElementName=CanvaContainer, Path=ActualHeight}" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter"/>
                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="11" Height="{Binding ElementName=CanvaContainer, Path=ActualHeight}" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter"/>
                </Grid>
            </Canvas>

        </Border>

        <Border HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="18" Margin="40,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="542" BorderBrush="Black" >
            <Grid x:Name="gridMonth">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition  Width="45" />
                    <ColumnDefinition  Width="45" />
                    <ColumnDefinition  Width="45" />
                    <ColumnDefinition  Width="45" />
                    <ColumnDefinition  Width="45" />
                    <ColumnDefinition  Width="45" />
                    <ColumnDefinition  Width="45" />
                    <ColumnDefinition  Width="45" />
                    <ColumnDefinition  Width="45" />
                    <ColumnDefinition  Width="45" />
                    <ColumnDefinition  Width="45" />
                    <ColumnDefinition  Width="45" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" CornerRadius="1" >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding sSep, Source={StaticResource Resources}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>

                <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" CornerRadius="1" >
                    <TextBlock   Text="{Binding sOct, Source={StaticResource Resources}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>

                <Border Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" CornerRadius="1" >
                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding sNov, Source={StaticResource Resources}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>

                <Border Grid.Column="3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" CornerRadius="1" >
                    <TextBlock   Text="{Binding sDec, Source={StaticResource Resources}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Column="4" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" CornerRadius="1" >
                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding sJan, Source={StaticResource Resources}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>

                <Border Grid.Column="5" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" CornerRadius="1" >
                    <TextBlock   Text="{Binding sFeb, Source={StaticResource Resources}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Column="6" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" CornerRadius="1" >
                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding sMar, Source={StaticResource Resources}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>

                <Border Grid.Column="7" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" CornerRadius="1" >
                    <TextBlock   Text="{Binding sApr, Source={StaticResource Resources}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Column="8" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" CornerRadius="1" >
                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding sMay, Source={StaticResource Resources}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>

                <Border Grid.Column="9" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" CornerRadius="1" >
                    <TextBlock   Text="{Binding sJune, Source={StaticResource Resources}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Column="10" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" CornerRadius="1" >
                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding sJul, Source={StaticResource Resources}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>

                <Border Grid.Column="11" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" CornerRadius="1" >
                    <TextBlock   Text="{Binding sAug, Source={StaticResource Resources}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </Border>

        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="480" Margin="0,230,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40">
            <Grid x:Name="depthLeader">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Border Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1" CornerRadius="3">
                    <TextBlock Name="depth0" Text="-0,25m" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1" CornerRadius="3">
                    <TextBlock Name="depth1" Text="-0,5m" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Row="2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1" CornerRadius="3">
                    <TextBlock Name="depth2" Text="-0,75m" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Row="3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1" CornerRadius="3">
                    <TextBlock Name="depth3" Text="-1m" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Row="4" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1" CornerRadius="3">
                    <TextBlock Name="depth4" Text="-1,5m" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Row="5" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1" CornerRadius="3">
                    <TextBlock Name="depth5" Text="-2m" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Row="6" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1" CornerRadius="3">
                    <TextBlock Name="depth6" Text="-2,5m" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Row="7" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1" CornerRadius="3">
                    <TextBlock Name="depth7" Text="-3m" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Row="8" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1" CornerRadius="3">
                    <TextBlock Name="depth8" Text="-3,5m" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Row="9" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1" CornerRadius="3">
                    <TextBlock Name="depth9" Text="-4m" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Row="10" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1" CornerRadius="3">
                    <TextBlock Name="depth10" Text="-4,5m" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Row="11" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,0,0,1" CornerRadius="3">
                    <TextBlock Name="depth11" Text="-5m" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </Border>

        <Button Margin="20,-10,542,590" Name="nextMonth" Content="&gt;" Background="LightGray" Width="20" Height="20" Click="nextMonth_Click"/>
        <Button  Margin="0,-10,562,590" Name="previousMonth" Content="&lt;" Background="LightGray" Width="20" Height="20" Click="previousMonth_Click"/>
        <Grid x:Name="AirTempGd" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="175" Margin="10,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="572"/>


    </Grid>
```

That would be the code I'm working one, I gave it to you all so you will get the context better. So my problem is the mouse enter event is not being called I,ve tried with breakpoint to console output and it's never getting called I don't know why I've also tried other event like MouseDown or MouseLeave and it's not working yet even with the background being transparent I have no clue where's my problem I could use some help.

***EDIT***

I may be wrong but I think it because it being in another container but I don't know if it's the problem and if it's I don't know how to fix it except removing container but I need them. But it would be stupid if this is the error so I would be surprised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason is your rectangle is missing content. Simple fix is to fill it with transparent color

```
<Rectangle Fill="Transparent" Grid.Column="0" Height="{Binding ElementName=CanvaContainer, Path=ActualHeight}" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter"
```